# cannot use operators in mongodb version 3.4

Tags: mongodb

I recently upgrade the version of mongodb. My previous version was 3.2

When I write on console;

```
mongod --version
db version v3.4.2
```

But I cannot use operators that comes with new version of mongodb (3.4) in MongoChef.

For example this one; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/

MongoChef doesn't complete or when I try to execute the string it throws an erroras;

```
the selection: invalid and cannot be executed.
```

Should I upgrade MongoChef as well? Why I cannot use the operators in version 3.4 while my mongodb version is it.

Comment: can you check the version of your mongo shell ? mongo --version

Comment: yes I run that command and it returned as; `mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your MongoChef Version as only MongoChef vertion 4.5 + are compatible with 3.4 according to the release notes.

With that, I would recommend upgrading to the latest MongoChef release 5.1 - https://studio3t.com/download/

MongoChef is now called Studio 3T now.